# How to check that an account is the owner of an onchain program?

Tags: solana-program, rust

```
use solana_program::{
    account_info::{next_account_info, AccountInfo},
    entrypoint,
    entrypoint::ProgramResult,
    msg,
    program_error::ProgramError,
    pubkey::Pubkey,
};

// Declare and export the program's entrypoint
entrypoint!(process_instruction);

// Program entrypoint's implementation
pub fn process_instruction(
    program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    _instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {

    let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();

    let account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;

   
    Ok(())
}
```

[onchain program on solana explorer](https://explorer.solana.com/address/9QkPwQVdRtktSxYUs4g7fd9CZC7VARJpotvCbWnuZNdX?cluster=devnet)

[image]

How to check that an `account` (pubkey 5ZLEmhSyVhLrgMvRu7KfreaRk1MX5aG3TKZLFStNihH) is the owner of a smart contract?

Answer (score 2):

You can check this using the solana cli using

```
 solana program show C3N7mj1oCrQNkzLW3dcaV7FrSbqJjbRX6BKkXePz2tFG
```

and you'll get an output like then one displayed below where the Authority is the owner.

```
Program Id: C3N7mj1oCrQNkzLW3dcaV7FrSbqJjbRX6BKkXePz2tFG
Owner: BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111
ProgramData Address: Do7fGfirJpNZRZJQNp8LWaXSnL9TNjE4sNaHz4ws6ctc
Authority: 4kg8oh3jdNtn7j2wcS7TrUua31AgbLzDVkBZgTAe44aF
Last Deployed In Slot: 254985418
Data Length: 1360096 (0x14c0e0) bytes
Balance: 9.46747224 SOL
```

If you want to check it, in the program, I assume that you are the one deploying the contract. That will make you the authority.

```
// Program entrypoint's implementation
pub fn process_instruction(
    program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    _instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {

    const AUTHORITY: &str = "5ZLEmhSyVhLrgMvRu7KfreaRk1MX5aG3TKZLFStNihH";


    let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
    let account_one = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?.key;

    
    if account_one != &Pubkey::from_str(AUTHORITY).unwrap() {
        msg!("only authority is allowed to call this function");
        return Err(solana_program::program_error::ProgramError::IllegalOwner);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: i want to do it in the program. How make it ? Сan you give an example code?

Comment: could you provide more context as to what you want to do?